# Wave Function plots changing on increasing the number of basis

Tags: scilab

```
N=15//no. of basis

b=%pi^2/4;

e2=30^2;//sq. of stiffness costant

a=2;//width of inf. potential well

h=zeros(N,N);//call h matrix

//hnm matrix

for n=1:N;

    h(n,n)=e2*((1-6/(%pi*%pi*n*n))*(%pi^2/48))+n^2;

    for m=n+1:N;

        q=1/((m-n)^2);

        r=1/((m+n)^2);

        t=((-1)^(m+n)+1)/4;

        h(m,n)=e2*t*(q-r);

        h(n,m)=h(m,n);

        end

end

disp(h);

//to find eigen values and matrix

s=eye(N,N);//elementary matrix

disp(s);

[al,be,R]=spec(h,s);

e1=al./be;

c=R;

disp(e1);//eigen values

disp(c);

[E,k]=gsort(real(e1),"g","d");//sorting eigen values

E=E;

disp(E);

d=c;

d(:,1:N)=c(:,k);//sorting eigen vectors

p=1000;

x=linspace(0,a,p);

psi=zeros(N,p);//call psi wave fn.

for m2=1:N;

    for n2=1:N;

        psi(m2,:)=psi(m2,:)+d(n2,m2)*sqrt(2/a)*sin(n2*%pi*x/a);

    end

    if(m2<=15);

        subplot(5,5,m2);

        plot(x,psi(m2,:));

        end

end
```

My question is this is an harmonic oscillator problem where i have chosen basis of an infinite square well and i have drawn the wave functions of it.My problem is as i increase my basis to 20 i.e N=20 the wave function plot just gets inverted which is not supposed to happen.So i want to know is there any problem in my code as physics cannot be wrong.

Comment: what is the question here? can you add more info to it and related tags?

Comment: @NithinKumarBiliya my question is this is an harmonic oscillator problem where i have chosen basis of an infinite square well and i have drawn the wave functions of it.My problem is as i increase my basis to 20 i.e N=20 the wave function plot just gets inverted which is not supposed to happen.So i want to know is there any problem in my code as physics cannot be wrong.

Comment: Your eigenvectors are defined up to a multiplicative constant (with arbitrary sign). Maybe that's the cause of your problem.

Comment: @StéphaneMottelet what could be the possible solution for it then? Can you add any light into the code itself?

Comment: The coefficient `sqrt(2/a)*sin(n2*%pi*x/a)` is likely theoretically determined with normalized eigenvectors. Without knowing this normalization I can't say more...

Comment: @StéphaneMottelet actually these are the basis of infinite square well upon which my wave function is expanded where sqrt(2/a) is the normalization constant for 1-d infinite potential.So i don't think there might be any problem in that as these are just simply basis upon which i have embedded my harmonic oscillator into it.As to expand a wave function we always need an normalized basis sets and as sin is a best example so we choose the basis sets of an infinite well.

Comment: @StéphaneMottelet ?

Comment: I repeat: your computation is based on eigenvectors, which are defined up to a mutiplicative constant, hence the result is forcibly not well defined. I cannot say more as I am not a quantum physics specialist. Maybe you could give me some pointers on some easy literature on your problem.